# Click link and the image scrolls down and some information is displayed in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create/reproduce in javascript language this effect  when I click on **"Parentesi Magazine 01"** on this web page

https://www.niccologaleotti.com/work2.html

By clicking on the link "Parentesi Magazine 01" the image scrolls down and some information is displayed

Any idea?

Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you provided uses jQuery to do that. Jquery is javascript package that offers some extended functionality and utility on top of vanilla javascript.

In particular they are using the jQuery slide() functions, which you can read more about here https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding . What you basically want to do is attach an event listener to the element which will trigger a slideToggle() to the text hidden text element. You first want to include the jquery library (before including your js code) and then in your code:

```
const $slideTrigger = $('.js-slide-trigger');
const $slideTarget = $('.js-slide-target');

$slideTrigger.on('click',function(event) {
  $slideTarget.slideToggle();
})
```

Where "js-slide-trigger" is the class of your trigger and "js-slide-target" is the class of the hidden element you want to toggle. Note that the slide element should have "display: none" in order to be hidden at first.
It should be something like that